# Getting null values of all parameters in method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce. I am making plugin. I want to add selected product in table Look_Product_Mapping. For that i have used popup(ProductAddPopup.cshtml) like adding products in category. When i save the product to add selected product.It execute ProductAddPopup method. but it get null value of all parameters and new record is inserted successfully.

I have used this code for "add new product" button which will open one **popup window**.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnAddNewProduct" name="btnAddNewProduct" value="@T("Admin.Catalog.Categories.Products.AddNew")" onclick="javascript:OpenWindow('@(Url.Action("ProductAddPopup", "LookBook", new {lookId = Model.Id, btnId = "btnRefreshProducts", formId = "products-form" }))    ', 800, 800, true); return false;" class="t-button" />
```

**Code for save button:**

```
 <input type="submit" name="save" class="t-button" value="@T("Admin.Common.Save")" />
```

**ProductAddPopup Method Code:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [FormValueRequired("save")]
        public ActionResult ProductAddPopup(string btnId, string formId, AddLookProductModel model)
        {
            if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCategories))
                return AccessDeniedView();

            if (model.SelectedProductIds != null)
            {
                foreach (int id in model.SelectedProductIds)
                {
                    var product = _productService.GetProductById(id);
                    if (product != null)
                    {
                        var existingProductLooks = _lookService.GetProductLookByLookId(model.LookId, 0, int.MaxValue, true);

                        if (existingProductLooks.FindProductLook(id, model.LookId) == null)
                        {
                            _lookService.InsertLookProduct(
                                new Look_Product_Mapping()
                                {
                                    LookId = model.LookId,
                                    ProductId = id,
                                    DisplayOrder = 1
                                });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ViewBag.RefreshPage = true;
            ViewBag.btnId = btnId;
            ViewBag.formId = formId;
            return View(model);
        }
```

Am i doing some thing wrong? 
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe your javascript method **OpenWindow** will finally use `window.open` and it will use a `GET` protocol to load a content

Try changing your action method with `HttpGet`

```
 [HttpGet]
 [FormValueRequired("save")]
  public ActionResult ProductAddPopup(string btnId, string formId,
      ddLookProductModel model)
   {
   }
```